# Column value not updated in the table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am not able to update one column field. Please Suggest me what is the wrong thing in my code

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $host    = "localhost";
  $user    = "root";
  $pass    = "";
  $db_name = "logistics";
  $lastId="";
  //create connection
  $con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM notification");
?>
<div class="table-inner-wrapper">
  <h5 class="text- blll"> Active Alerts </h5>
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr class="t_head">
      <th>ID </th>
      <th>Forklift ID</th>
      <th>Timestamp</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Alert Details</th>
      <th></th>
      <th>Remark</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<form action='' id='remarks' method='post'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['forklift_id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['noti_start'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['duration'] . " hr</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['alert_details'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><i class='email' id='". $row['id'] ."'> &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-inbox fa-2x'> </i> </i> </td>";
        echo "<td><textarea class='remarks' id='".$row['id']."'> ".$row['remarks']."  </textarea></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-info remark' value='submit' id='".$row['id']."'></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</form>";
      }
    ?>
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(() => {

    $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".remark").on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var remarks    = $("textarea.remarks").val();
        //  alert(remarks);
        // alert(id);
        $.ajax({
          url:'remark.php',
          method:'POST',
          data: {id: id, remarks: remarks},
          success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            // return data;
          }
        });
      });
    });

  })
</script>
```

**remark.php**

```
<?php
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'logistics');

  $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
  echo $remarks;
  $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
  echo $id;

  $sql = "UPDATE notification SET remarks='".$remarks."' WHERE id='".$id."' " ;

  if($conn->query($sql)===TRUE){
    echo "DATA updated";
  }
?>
```

I am trying to update remarks column value on submit based on row id but it's  updating only a first row of column value and if i click on the remaining rows it is not updating the remarks value.

Comment: are try to multiple insert query ?

Comment: do you read error logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things:

I would change `$id = $_REQUEST['id'];` to `$id = $_POST['id'];`

Secondly, your `<form>` tag is inside your while loop which means you are echoing out a new form on every iteration.  All of the forms will have the same id.  This will cause you problems and fits the type of behavior that you are describing.  Remove the `<form>` tags from the inside of the loop like so:

```
echo "<form action='' id='remarks' method='post'>"; 

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['forklift_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['noti_start'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['duration'] . " hr</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['alert_details'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td><i class='email' id='". $row['id'] ."'> &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-inbox fa-2x'> </i> </i> </td>";
    echo "<td><textarea class='remarks' id='".$row['id']."'> ".$row['remarks']."  </textarea></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-info remark' value='submit' id='".$row['id']."'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";


  }

echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var remarks = $("textarea.remarks").val();
```

will only give you the value of the first `textarea` with the class `remarks`. You need to access the remarks from the textarea associated with the button instead. You do have a problem though that you have multiple elements with the same `id`, so you need to fix that first. Try changing this code:

```
echo "<td><i class='email' id='". $row['id'] ."'> &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-inbox fa-2x'> </i> </i> </td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='remarks' id='".$row['id']."'> ".$row['remarks']."  </textarea></td>";
```

to

```
echo "<td><i class='email' id='e". $row['id'] ."'> &nbsp;<i class='fa fa-inbox fa-2x'> </i> </i> </td>";
echo "<td><textarea class='remarks' id='t".$row['id']."'> ".$row['remarks']."  </textarea></td>";
```

Now your textarea field has a unique `id` which is still related to `$row['id']`. So in your event code, you can write:

```
var remarks = $("#t" + id).val();
```

to get the value of remarks associated with that button.